# angular2 can't render <tr> as a component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to render a table row as a component:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Imię</th>
            <th>Nazwisko</th>
            <th>Data od</th>
            <th>Data do</th>
            <th>Pokój</th>
            <th>Typ pokoju</th>
            <th>Cena</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <app-rezerwacja-item
            *ngFor="let rezerwacjaEl of rezerwacje; let i = index"
            [rezerwacja]="rezerwacjaEl"
            [index]="i">
        </app-rezerwacja-item>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[rezerwacja-item-component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kR9a.png)

But the browser renders `app-rezerwacja-item` first, then a row, and the table can't "see" the rows as rows. They are off the grid. The table also crashes.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: updated with a link (cant format the code inside stack's editor)

Comment: What I know , if you need to modify the behavior or tr, create it as a directive rather than component

Comment: So each rezerwacjaEl should be a row (<tr>) ?

Comment: @Vega yes, but each time it generates <app-rezerwacja-item> before <tr> wchich causes table creash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set 'app-rezerwacja-item' as the part of the selector. I didn't have your code, so adapted this example:

**parent HTML**

```
  <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr app-rezerwacja-item *ngFor="let rezerwacjaEl of rezerwacje; let i = index"
            [rezerwacja]="rezerwacjaEl"
            [index]="i">
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Child component class:**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'tr [app-rezerwacja-item]',
  template: `
    <td>{{rezerwacja.name}}</td>
  `
})
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqydnh?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Hey, i've got error:
Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.

Comment: I updated the demo and the post. Could you make a brief demo? Fork the demo in my post and update it, save it and give me the link

Comment: Can I also ask how to attach <a> tag to <tr> tag?

Comment: like this: <a
      style="cursor: pointer;"
      [routerLink]="[index]"
      routerLinkActive="active"
      class="list-group-item clearfix">

Comment: I am not sure to get correctly. Do you wish to put the anchor tag in the child component?

Comment: around the tr tag would be not correct as html syntax, inside tr tag, I don't see the complexity, just put it as you have, just index should be a  correct route

Comment: Could you fork my demo copy your code and save, give me the link, so I can see the what's going on?

Comment: I just want to add [routerLink]="[index]" > to my <tr> tag to navigate to detal componnt, but html refuses to do it. just like there would be <a> tag